# LibGDX - How to slow down update() method?

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d-games

I'm trying to recreate Space Invaders in LibGDX to get grip on game-developing but when I try to set every enemy (for now they are just squares) to move in sequence the update() method makes them change their postitions way too fast. Is there some way to slow down this rendering on whole project or any other proper way to solve this? I also tried to handle movement in Timer class and scheulde it but it caused memory overload and threads weren't fired in the same time for every object.

```
  package regularmikey.objects;

  import java.util.Timer;
  import java.util.TimerTask;

  import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;

  public class Aliens {

public float x;
public float y;
public float fx;
public float fy;
public int step_count = 0;

public Aliens(float x, float y) {
    this.fx = this.x = x;
    this.fy = this.y = y;


};


public void update(float dt){

    if(step_count == 10) { 
        step_count = 0;
        y = y - 1;
        x = fx; 

    }
    x = x + 3;
    step_count++;
 };
```

PlayState class

```
package regularmikey.gamestates;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;

import regularmikey.managers.GameStateManager;
import regularmikey.objects.Aliens;
import regularmikey.objects.Bullet;
import regularmikey.objects.Player;

public class PlayState extends GameState {

private Player player;
private ArrayList<Bullet> bullets;
private ArrayList<Aliens> aliens;
private ShapeRenderer sr;

public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {

    super(gsm);

}

@Override
public void init() {
    sr = new ShapeRenderer();
    bullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
    aliens =  new ArrayList<Aliens>();
    player = new Player(bullets);
    spawnAliens();




}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    player.update(dt);

    for(int i = 0; i < aliens.size(); i++) {
        aliens.get(i).update(dt);
    }



}

public void spawnAliens() {
    aliens.clear();



    float i, j;



    for(j = 100; j <= 510; j = j + 45) {
        for(i = 250; i <= 445; i =  i + 45) {

            aliens.add(new Aliens(j, i));
        }

    }




}

@Override
public void draw() {
    player.draw(sr);



    for(int i = 0; i < aliens.size(); i++) {
        aliens.get(i).draw(sr);

    }



}

@Override
public void handleinput() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}


public void draw(ShapeRenderer sr) {
    sr.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    sr.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    sr.rect(x, y, 30, 30);
    sr.end();


};


}
```

Answer (score 3):

The key here is the `dt` variable that is passed along with the `update()` method, which is short for Delta Time.

Delta time is a commonly used factor in game development that represents the time that has passed since the last frame.

I can't exactly make out the way you are making your aliens move about, but the usual way to make entities in your game move smoothly (regardless of the frame rate):

```
void update(float deltaTime){
    this.position = currentPosition + (this.movementSpeed × deltaTime);
}
```

This doesn't take into consideration the direction in which the entity is moving, amongst others. But that is besides the point of this example.

So, in your case, you could so something like this:

```
package regularmikey.objects;

  import java.util.Timer;
  import java.util.TimerTask;

  import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;

  public class Aliens {

public float x;
public float y;
public float fx;
public float fy;
public int step_count = 0;

private float moveTimer;
private float moveTreshold;

public Aliens(float x, float y) {
    this.fx = this.x = x;
    this.fy = this.y = y;

    moveTimer = 0; // This will act as a stopwatch
    moveTreshold = 3000; // Alien will move once it passes this treshold
};


public void update(float dt){
    // check whether we passed the treshold for moving or not
    if(moveTimer += dt; > moveTreshold){
      if(step_count == 10) { 
          step_count = 0;
          y = y - 1;
          x = fx; 

      }
      x = x + 3;
      step_count++;

      moveTimer = 0; // reset the timer
    }
 };
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exacly what I wanted.